# Using structure in C and C++

Tags: c, structure

I am new to C and I want to know how to access elements inside a structure which is placed inside a structure.

```
struct profile_t
{
    unsigned char length;
    unsigned char type;
    unsigned char *data;
};

typedef struct profile_datagram_t
{
    unsigned char src[4];
    unsigned char dst[4];
    unsigned char ver;
    unsigned char n;
    struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];     
} header;
```

How to access elements inside profile_t??

Comment: +1 This must be a tough question, because the first two answerers were wrong.

Comment: @Chris - or people think they know C better than they actually do.

Comment: @Hogan - True. Still, dark corners like this are good questions, because they expose the holes in peoples' knowledge.

Comment: You haven't placed a structure inside a structure, you've just declared a type. Do you mean `struct profile_t profile;`?

Comment: I'm more fascinated by the answers than the question. The brain compiler is really bad sometimes.

Comment: @Mike Seymour - No, the above works on several compilers (but is nonstandard). See my answer.

Comment: In my commotion to correct people I forgot to mention that C and C++ are not the same language, or even sufficiently similar that you should aim for compatibility between them. There are many C-isms that are horrible code in C++, and many C++-isms that either won't work or are unnecessary noise in C. Writing code that works for both guarantees that it's bad for both. If you're using pure C, don't be afraid to stick to your guns (even when they shoot you in the foot). Likewise, if you're writing C++, don't add the `[c]` tag.

Comment: @Charles: writing code for both does not guarantee it's bad for both.  At least, making the header file (where such types are often declared) compatible for both makes life easier for everybody.

Comment: @André - Header files are easy to make compatible though. People get into trouble when they try to make all their code compile as both. And aside from header files, it does. `int *x = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));` is bad in both C (casting `void *` types hurts maintainability) and C++ (C casts should be avoided in C++), but there's no other way to have dynamic memory if you're writing both C and C++.

Comment: I am getting an error: expected identifier or â(â before â.â token
wherever I tried to intialise the elements. I have intialised them as:header.src[0] =1;
 header.dst[0] = 2;
 header.ver = 1;
 header.n = 2;
 header.profiles.length = 10;
 header.profiles.type = 1;

Answer (score 5):

```
struct profile_t;
```

The above statement doesn't create an object of type `profile_t`. What you need to do is -

```
struct profile_t inObj ;
```

Then create object for `profile_datagram_t`. i.e.,

```
header outObj ;  // header typedef for profile_datagram_t
```

Now you can access elements like -

```
outObj.inObj.type = 'a' ; // As an example
```

In C++, while creation of object for a structure, **struct** key word isn't necessary.

---

On your question edit and comment :

```
struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];
```

`profiles` is an array of objects of type `profile_t`. To access the individual object, just use the `[]` operator. i.e.,

```
header obj ;
obj.profiles[0].type = 'a' ; // Example
```

`obj.profiles[i]`, where `i` can take values from **0** to **MAXPROFILES - 1**, gives the object at index `i`.

Comment: Actually, it does place a `struct profile_t` inside the `header` struct in some compilers. Google "anonymous struct."

Comment: @Peter R. - I know, but it appears to be compiling, so this is probably the behavior the OP is observing. Some people don't mind using nonstandard extensions.

Comment: @Chris He should be able to access the elements directly header obj; obj.length; then but this is bad practice to say the least...

Comment: @Peter R. - Apparently this behavior is being added to the upcoming C1X standard. So maybe it's not such a bad practice? (Just keep it to one or two `struct`s / levels to avoid any headache).

Comment: I would think that by any of the ordinary rules, `struct profile_t` in this spot could only possibly be a (useless and redundant) forward declaration. (In C++, specifically, the declaration of an inner struct `profile_datagram_t::profile_t`.)

Answer (score 2):

Some compilers support a nonstandard extension to the C language (that I actually rather like, despite it being nonstandard) called anonymous structs (or unions). Code demonstration:

```
struct x {
  int i;
};

struct y {
  struct x;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct y;
    y.i = 1; // this accesses member i of the struct x nested in struct y
    return 0;
}
```

In a nutshell, if you don't give the `struct` (or `union`) member a name, you can access its members directly from the containing `struct` (or `union`). This is useful in situations where you might have given it the name `_`, and had to do `y._.i` - the anonymous struct syntax is much simpler. However, it does mean that you have to remember the names of all members of both `struct`s and ensure they never clash.

This is all, of course, a nonstandard extension, and should be used with caution. I believe it works on MSVC and can be enabled in GCC with a switch. Don't know about any other compilers. If you're worried about portability, give the member a proper name.

EDIT: According to the GCC reference (below) this behavior is being added to the upcoming C1X standard, so it won't be nonstandard for long. I doubt MSVC will support C1X since they refuse to support C99 as it is, but at least this feature is becoming part of the standard.

However, the behavior shown above is MSVC only. The C1X (and GCC without the `-fms-extensions` switch) syntax doesn't allow the unnamed `struct` member to have a name:

```
struct y {
  struct {
    int i;
  };
};

int main(void) {
    struct y;
    y.i = 1; // this accesses member i of the struct x nested in struct y
    return 0;
}
```

References for various compilers (they have different names but are the same concept):
**GCC** (unnamed fields): http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html'
**MSVC** (anonymous structs): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f.aspx

Comment: Funny, the result is completely different in C++.  Check my answer.

Comment: It does NOT work on MSVC and should not be used. It has no benefit at all over using standard code and actually giving the member a proper name.

Comment: @André - The C++ result is much better (for C++). I hadn't thought about it from a C++ angle, but it is interesting. I suspect the OP is using C, however.

Comment: @Peter R. - The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cx9y4f.aspx) says otherwise. I'm on a Mac so I can't exactly test it. (And I don't endorse nonstandard behavior, but sometimes people write closed-source code for one target compiler and like to use the funky extensions said compiler provides. I'm not endorsing, just explaining.)

Comment: @Chris Actually I wasn't looking at the documentation; I just tried the code with MSVC and it complained.

Comment: @Peter R. - Did you compile it as C (instead of C++)? If that's not the problem, it may need a flag or something, but I can't help you there.

Comment: @Charles: indeed, if you right-click on the file in the solution explorer, properties: "C++ -> Advanced -> Comple As -> C".  Or, set the file extension to ".c" and it does so by default.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what happends in C, but in C++, rest of the stuff aside, the following declares two types.

```
struct profile_datagram_t
{
    struct profile_t;
};
```

One type is named `profile_datagram_t` and the other is called `profile_datagram_t::profile_t`.  The inner type declaration is just a forward declaration, so you'll need to define the type after.

```
struct profile_datagram_t::profile_t
{
    // ...
};
```

Then, you can use the struct as follows:

```
int main ( int, char ** )
{
    profile_datagram_t::profile_t profile;
}
```

Comment: Note: although the question is tagged "C", the title says "C and C++".

Comment: I suspect the OP means C, and has just tagged it C++ because many people conflate the two (especially when they're first learning).

Comment: It's also good to know these incompatibilities when porting code or interfacing C with C++.

Comment: True. I personally hate the idea of "upgrading" C to C++, but interfacing is always good thing.

Comment: @Chris: I said "port", not "upgrade" ;-)  Also, I sometimes write some core stuff in pure C as a standalone library.  It has the benefit of serving more than one language (e.g. easy interop with C++, Python, Ruby, Javascript, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use the following format:

```
variable = profile_t.element
profile_t.element = ?
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: In your declaration of profile_datagram_t, the proper definition for struct profile_t should be:

```
struct profile_t someProfile;
```

Let's say you have:

```
header profileDiagram1;
struct profile_t profile1;
profileDiagram1.someProfile = profile1;
```

To access length, type or *data from profile_t:

```
profileDiagram1.someProfile.type;
profileDiagram1.someProfile.length;
...
```